# How to get Product attribute from Cart Model

Tags: magento2, cart

I am trying to get the product attributes using the below 2 ways from the checkout cart model code but it is not working.

```
public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    
    // First Way to get attribute value
    
    // get quote items collection
    $itemsCollection = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();   
    foreach($itemsCollection as $item){
        
        // Below two lines not returning attribute value
        $logger->info($item->getAttribute('country_of_manufacture'));
        $logger->info($item->getProduct()->getCountryOfManufacture());
    }
    
    // Second Way to get attribute value
    
    // get quote items array
    $items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();    
    foreach($items as $item) {          
        
       // Below three lines not returning attribute value
        $country_of_manufacture  = $item->getCountryOfManufacture();
        $country_of_manufacture = $item->getProduct()->getAttribute('country_of_manufacture');
        $country_of_manufacture = $item->getProduct()->getData('country_of_manufacture');
        
        $logger->info('Country: '.$country_of_manufacture); 
    }
    
    return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new concept in Magento 2 to create a catalog_attributes.xml file in which you can define your custom attribute value using the quote_item group section

You Just need to create app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/catalog_attributes.xml with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="country_of_manufacture"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

you can get custom_attribute_name in the template file withcart/item/default.phtml below code.

```
<?= $_item->getProduct()->getData('custom_attribute_name');?>
```

Refresh the Cache and that’s it.

Comment: Thank you it is working, how to get the value of a select field `<?= $_item->getProduct()->getData('country_of_manufacture');?>` returns value not actual text.

Comment: I got it using `$item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('country_of_manufacture')`

Comment: its working code then give an upvote for this answer